# Database access connection string

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

So I am currently having a problem with my database connection string. Every time I need to re-enter the string if I were to use the project in another pc is there a way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: use a relative path?

Comment: can you explain im new to this

Comment: instead of full path (like `C:\Folder\Folder\bla-bla-bla\SubFolder\File.txt`) you can use relative path (like `.\SubFolder\File.txt`)

Comment: tried it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

**|DataDirectory|** (enclosed in pipe symbols) is a substitution string that indicates the path to the database. It eliminates the need to hard-code the full path which leads to several problems as the full path to the database could be serialized in different places. DataDirectory also makes it easy to share a project and also to deploy an application.

For example, instead of having the following connection string:

`"Data Source= c:\program files\MyApp\Mydb.sdf"`

Using DataDirectory, you can have the following connection string:

`"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Mydb.sdf"`

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce

Comment: like for example i can view the database but cant seem to insert also im using accdb

Comment: `Cant seem to insert`, it has to be more specific than that. What exact error did you get, stack trace etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current user's Desktop folder and then the subfolder of this:

```cs
const string databasePath = @"quiz\Quiz1\Db.accdb";

string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string connectionPath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, databasePath);

Console.WriteLine(connectionPath);
```